# Whitebox tool not in QGIS 3.16.5

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-plugins, elevation, contour

In QGIS 3.16.5 I can not see a whitebox tools to create contour from raster. Why the whitebox tool does not appear in my QGIS version?

Comment: QGIS doesn't come with whitebox tools, you need to install it as well as the plugin - https://jblindsay.github.io/wbt_book/qgis_plugin.html

Comment: The Whitebox Tools is a "third party" tool that you need install.  You need to add it to the QGIS repository before you can install it.

Comment: What is wrong with the native tool QGIS provides?

Comment: @Erik There are some tools that work faster (filters for raster, for example), many tools for lidar processing. It is a set of utilities that allows expanding the capabilities of Qgis, in my opinion

Comment: @ Aigbe from the link of user 2856 you have to take in to account also that: "Note that the QGIS plugin does not come with a copy of the WhiteboxTools executable and so you will still need to download WhiteboxTools from either the Geomorphometry and Hydrogeomatics Research Group website or the WhiteboxTools Github repository prior to running the plugin"